# Pop Up Button menu items

Tags: xcode, popup, interface-builder, xcode4.5

Okay, I am using Interface Builder in Xcode 4.5.1 and just added a Pop Up Button to the window.  If I click through I see "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", which are editable.  I was expecting to see something in the attributes or identity inspector that let me define how many of these items were in the menu, but there is nothing there.  I've been looking at this for hours.  Where can these be defined?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It figures... just when I give up and try something else:
The circular button on the lower right with the triangle let me "Show the document outline".  Once here, the outline elements are editable, copy paste, change name etc.

So, under "Menu - OtherViews", the "Menu Item - ..." can be deleted or copy/pasted to add.

This took hours of my life that I will never get back, I hope someone else finds this tip useful.

Comment: Someone did find this helpful! I just added items programmatically, this is a bit simpler.